# Why tausend (not dausend)?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

Why are
**th**ree **d**rei
**th**ou **d**u
**th**orn **D**orn
**th**in **d**ünn
**th**en **d**ann

but
**th**ousand **t**ausend?

Comment: Your examples changed between Old High German and Middle Low German for the most part, as far as I know it usually this comes down to effort and useage. It's likely that since fewer people count to thousand, especially before the 18th century, it was used less it would not have changed as strongly.

Comment: Why  "It's likely that since fewer people count to thousand, especially before the 18th century"? Wouldn't any year of that century already imply *Tausend*? (I myself haven't ever counted to thousand either, but I know the number).

Comment: @c.p. like Neunzehnhundert, achtzehnhundert, siebzehnhundert .... ?

Comment: @HalvarF You are right, my argument is wrong. But was money also counted like that? And people? Or apples?

Comment: Another example: **th**aw **t**auen.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Daus. I also know "den Daus" as "the devil" but have no source to cite.

Comment: @c.p. I just picked an arbitrary year, I mostly meant that language is mostly molded by the masses of people, who would have enough things to count to thousand a lot. Rich people and businessmen might have been counting in the thousands on the regular, but the general population probably much less so. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Uwe. Yes, and this is another good example of the phenomenon discussed in my answer. "Tauen" owes its t- to phrases like "es taut", "das Eis taut". "Dauen" survives in "verdauen".

Comment: Swabian pronounces it with the soft sound, like “dausend”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indo-European *t normally becomes *Þ in proto-Germanic and then /d/ in High German. You have cited some examples for this. But thousand/tausend is an exception. In Old High German we have both the expected dūsunt and the unexpected tūsent. This variation is an example of “Notker’s Anlautgesetz”, which (simply put) stipulates that initial voiced stops b, d, g become voiceless if they are preceded in close junction by a word ending in a voiceless consonant. In this case, compounds like (the ancestor of) “fünf tausend”, “sechs tausend” have their /t/ by assimilation to the preceding voiceless consonant. The form with t- then gets generalised in all contexts.

Answer (score 0):

English *thousand* and German *tausend* are really cognates:

Modern German: *tausend* pronunciation: [ˈtaʊ̯zn̩t], [ˈtaʊ̯zɛnt]
Modern Englisch: *thousand* [ˈθaʊzn̩t], [ˈθaʊzənd]

Middle High German: *tusend* [ˈtuːzɛnt]
Old High German: *thusend* [ˈtʰuːzɛnt] (note, that [tʰ] is **not** [θ]) but also *dusund* [ˈduːsʊnt], [ˈduːzʊnt]

Old English: *þusend* (probably [ˈθuːzɛnt])

---

But there are many German words where *»t«* (pronounced as [t] or [tʰ]) and  *»d«* ([d]) where replaced by each other over the centuries. Examples are:

- **Brod** (valid spelling up to 1901) - **Brot** (modern) (both mean: *bread*)
- **Geld,** (money), Ent**gelt** (reward, fee) and **gelt**en (to count, to be valid, to weigh) which all derive from the same root.
- der **Tod** (noun: the death) - **tot** (adjective: dead)
- die **Schuld** (noun: the guilt, the blame, the fault) - der **Schult**heiß (old word for a sheriff or village mayor, literal: *the guilt-namer* or *guilt-stater*, i.e. a person who states other people to be guilty, i.e. a judge)

---

Where I grew up (south-east of Austria) the letters *»t«* and *»d«* are often pronounced with the same sound which is somewhere between [t] and [d] (maybe more on the [d]-side), so that these pairs are pronounced almost equally:

- danken - tanken
- Dusche - Tusche
- Deich - Teich

And I believe, that this did happen in other regions too, and so the sounds (and therefor also the letters) *t* and *d* often were swapped.